# Best Option for Speeding Up the Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I have an older AMD processor with integrated graphics (AMD Athlon II x4 640) and the android emulator runs really slow. The integrated graphics don't work with the "Use Host GPU" option and I can't use the faster Intel system images because I have an AMD processor.

I have heard Genymotion is faster but I can't use it since my integrated graphics don't support OpenGl 2.0+.

What would be the best upgrade: getting a graphics card or getting a new computer with an Intel processor?

Comment: geting an actual device is out of the question?

Comment: I want to be able to test in multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

A physical mobile phone connected via USB is faster than the emulator running on a amd rig.  My current budget forces me to test this way but hey there mobile apps might as well do some testing when I'm out and about.

I apologize in advance for recommending a purchase of a product which is not allowed but you can get a decent inexpensive no contract phone in the US a lot cheaper than a new intel rig.

Comment: I know you said a physical device was out of the question.  I can't however recommend purchasing a new intel rig as this would be a breach of the user agreement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps to speed up Android Emulator

1)Install HAXM in your SDK manager>Extras>HAXM.

2)Create Lower RAM Size Emulator if you have less RAM in your computer.

3)Close Other Unnecessary Process from TaskManager while you are running Emulator.

4)Use less Screen density(ldpi,mdpi) at the start.

5)Increase RAM of Your Computer Emulator will speed up.

6)Update your sdk with latest update

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try some of those.

Comment: I can't use HAXM though because I have an AMD processor.

Comment: You can try other option other than HAXM

Comment: I increased the ram of the emulator and that helped some.